# How to wrap text in Vaadin text area? It is by default taking style for white-space: nowrap

Tags: vaadin, vaadin14

My HTML:

```html
<div class="text-sm margin-bottom-xs" id="abcDiv">
  <div>
    <p class="padding-bottom-xs label_styles">Message</p>
    <vaadin-text-area id="abc" style="border: 1px solid black; padding: 1em; width:100%"></vaadin-text-area>
  </div>
</div>
```

And it looks like this:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

As seen in [the V14 documentation](https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/ds/components/text-area), the TextArea component does, in fact, wrap text inside it by default through `white-space: pre-wrap`. Perhaps you have some custom CSS in your application that overrides that?

Comment: Which file it should be which contain custom CSS that overrides these properties? any Idea?

Comment: There are to many files in project structure which contains .css files. Not sure which file properties overriding.

Comment: As the native <textarea> element is inside the component's shadow DOM, there are two ways you could apply CSS to it:
1. If using a theme folder, {themename}/components/vaadin-text-area.css
2. If loading stylesheets through `@CssImport`, you should look for `@CssImport` annotations with the themeFor="vaadin-text-area" parameter

Comment: The CSS selector almost certainly includes `[part="value"]` or `textarea`, so you could do a search through all .css files for those (although part=value will match other components too)

Comment: @SSL Now that you know what to look for, inspect the textarea in your browser, open the computed tab and filter for the property you are interested. Un-folding the property shows you what places influence the used value.

Comment: Rolf,  We dont have @CssImport and theme for vaadin-text-area. But for other components we have both. 
We have styles by defualt to text area:

[part="value"], [part="input-field"] ::slotted(input), [part="input-field"] ::slotted(textarea), [part="input-field"] ::slotted([part="value"]) {
  flex: auto;
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
}

Comment: Oh, I think I get it now: You are not using the default Lumo theme, instead you're using either Material (`@Theme(Material.class)`) or no theme (`@NoTheme`). In that case what you probably want to do is add that `white-space` yourself by adding `@CssImport(value="textarea.css", themeFor="vaadin-text-area")` and, in that stylesheet, `[part="value"] { white-space: pre-wrap; }`

Comment: Edit to the above: Material theme would also have the correct white-space in place, so in all likelihood you're on @NoTheme, which means you have to apply 95% of all CSS yourself. It's not an approach I would recommend, but if that's the way you need to go, then you need to get aquainted with applying CSS to the shadow DOM of components. See e.g. https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/styling/overview